# PHP Mailer array error

Tags: php, email

Having an annoying error with PHPMailer and can't figure what it's for

Mails send fine with it, but I get this:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in /dir/class.phpmailer.php on line 574
```

Any idea's?

CODE:

```
if (!in_array('PHPMailerAutoload', spl_autoload_functions())) {
  require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  }
```

class.phpmailer.php is 2000+ lines long, obviously I can't paste it all

Comment: It says everything you need to know. `in_array` expects the second parameter to be an array. But a boolean is passed. Show us line 574 and affected lines.

Comment: please put your all code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your spl autoload is empty, that's why it returns a boolean, false.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php

Try the following:

```
if (!spl_autoload_functions() OR (!in_array('PHPMailerAutoload', spl_autoload_functions()))) {
  require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
}
```

Comment: This bug is fixed in the latest dev-master of phpmailer.

Answer (score 1):

See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-functions.php) of spl_autoload_functions:

> If the autoload stack is not activated then the return value is FALSE.

You need to check this first.

Answer (score 1):

Folks should go a bit easy on OP... this is an error in the PHPMailer code, not in the OP's  code. The accepted answer is a solution for fixing the PHOMailer IITB code. Thanks for answering it Michal-sk!

Answer (score 0):

Your spl_autoload_functions() returns boolean not array.

It should be an array.